# how can I fix sql type error with diesel and juniper for mysql in graphQL mutation?

Tags: mysql, rust, graphql, rust-diesel, juniper

I confronted the error logs below when I try to create mutation with graphGL and mysql via diesel.

currently the type of enum is just diesel's type but I want to make that with graphQl's type.
I implemented Customer Structure for graphQL like below.
is it not enough ? and do you have any idea to fix that ?
Thanks

Error log

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `graphql::Customer: diesel::Queryable<(diesel::sql_types::Unsigned<diesel::sql_types::BigInt>, diesel::sql_types::Text, diesel::sql_types::Text, diesel::sql_types::Timestamp, diesel::sql_types::Timestamp), _>` is not satisfied
  --> src/graphql.rs:60:14
   |
60 |             .first::<crate::graphql::Customer>(&executor.context().db_con)
   |              ^^^^^ the trait `diesel::Queryable<(diesel::sql_types::Unsigned<diesel::sql_types::BigInt>, diesel::sql_types::Text, diesel::sql_types::Text, diesel::sql_types::Timestamp, diesel::sql_types::Timestamp), _>` is not implemented for `graphql::Customer`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `diesel::query_dsl::LoadQuery<_, graphql::Customer>` for `diesel::query_builder::SelectStatement<schema::customers::table, diesel::query_builder::select_clause::DefaultSelectClause, diesel::query_builder::distinct_clause::NoDistinctClause, diesel::query_builder::where_clause::NoWhereClause, diesel::query_builder::order_clause::NoOrderClause, diesel::query_builder::limit_clause::LimitClause<diesel::expression::bound::Bound<diesel::sql_types::BigInt, i64>>>`
```

src/graphql.rs

```
use std::convert::From;
use std::sync::Arc;
use chrono::NaiveDateTime; 
use actix_web::{web, Error, HttpResponse};
use futures01::future::Future;

use juniper::http::playground::playground_source;
use juniper::{http::GraphQLRequest, Executor, FieldResult, FieldError,ID};
use juniper_from_schema::graphql_schema_from_file;

use diesel::prelude::*;

use itertools::Itertools;
use crate::schema::customers;

use crate::{DbCon, DbPool};

graphql_schema_from_file!("src/schema.graphql");

pub struct Context {
    db_con: DbCon,
}
impl juniper::Context for Context {}

pub struct Query;
pub struct Mutation;

impl QueryFields for Query {
    fn field_customers(
        &self,
        executor: &Executor<'_, Context>,
        _trail: &QueryTrail<'_, Customer, Walked>,
    ) -> FieldResult<Vec<Customer>> {
        //type FieldResult<T> = Result<T, String>;

        customers::table
            .load::<crate::models::Customer>(&executor.context().db_con)
            .and_then(|customers| Ok(customers.into_iter().map_into().collect()))
            .map_err(Into::into)
    }
}

impl MutationFields for Mutation {
    fn field_create_customer(
        &self,
        executor: &Executor<'_, Context>,
        _trail: &QueryTrail<'_, Customer, Walked>,
        name: String,
        email: String,
    ) -> FieldResult<Customer> {
        //type FieldResult<T> = Result<T, String>;

        let new_customer = crate::models::NewCustomer { name: name, email: email};

        diesel::insert_into(customers::table)
            .values(&new_customer)
            .execute(&executor.context().db_con);
            
        customers::table
            .first::<crate::graphql::Customer>(&executor.context().db_con)
            .map_err(Into::into)
    }
}

pub struct Customer {
    id: u64,
    name: String,
    email: String,
    created_at: NaiveDateTime,
    updated_at: NaiveDateTime,
}

impl CustomerFields for Customer {
    fn field_id(&self, _: &Executor<'_, Context>) -> FieldResult<juniper::ID> {
        Ok(juniper::ID::new(self.id.to_string()))
    }

    fn field_name(&self, _: &Executor<'_, Context>) -> FieldResult<&String> {
        Ok(&self.name)
    }
    fn field_email(&self, _: &Executor<'_, Context>) -> FieldResult<&String> {
        Ok(&self.email)
    }
}

impl From<crate::models::Customer> for Customer {
    fn from(customer: crate::models::Customer) -> Self {
        Self {
            id: customer.id,
            name: customer.name,
            email: customer.email,
            created_at: customer.created_at,
            updated_at: customer.updated_at,
        }
    }
}

fn playground() -> HttpResponse {
    let html = playground_source("");
    HttpResponse::Ok()
        .content_type("text/html; charset=utf-8")
        .body(html)
}

fn graphql(
    schema: web::Data<Arc<Schema>>,
    data: web::Json<GraphQLRequest>,
    db_pool: web::Data<DbPool>,
) -> impl Future<Item = HttpResponse, Error = Error> {
    let ctx = Context {
        db_con: db_pool.get().unwrap(),
    };

    web::block(move || {
        let res = data.execute(&schema, &ctx);
        Ok::<_, serde_json::error::Error>(serde_json::to_string(&res)?)
    })
    .map_err(Error::from)
    .and_then(|customer| {
        Ok(HttpResponse::Ok()
            .content_type("application/json")
            .body(customer))
    })
}

pub fn register(config: &mut web::ServiceConfig) {
    let schema = std::sync::Arc::new(Schema::new(Query, Mutation));

    config
        .data(schema)
        .route("/", web::post().to_async(graphql))
        .route("/", web::get().to(playground));
}
```

src/models.rs

```
#[derive(Queryable, Identifiable, AsChangeset, Clone, PartialEq, Debug)]
pub struct Customer {
    pub id: u64,
    pub name: String,
    pub email: String,
    pub created_at: NaiveDateTime,
    pub updated_at: NaiveDateTime,
}

use super::schema::customers;
#[derive(Queryable,Insertable, AsChangeset)]
#[table_name="customers"]
pub struct NewCustomer {
    pub name: String,
    pub email: String,
}
```

Dependencies

```
[dependencies]
diesel = { version = "1.4.5", features = ["mysql", "r2d2", "chrono"] }
dotenv = "~0.15"
serde = "~1.0"
serde_derive = "~1.0"
serde_json = "~1.0"
chrono = "~0.4"
rand = "0.7.3"
actix-web = "1.0.9"
actix-cors = "0.1.0"
juniper = "0.14.1"
juniper-from-schema = "0.5.1"
juniper-eager-loading = "0.5.0"
r2d2_mysql = "*"
r2d2-diesel = "0.16.0"
mysql = "*"
r2d2 = "*"
futures01 = "0.1.29"
itertools = "0.8.2"
```

src/schema.graphql

```
schema {
  query: Query
  mutation: Mutation
}

type Query {
  customers: [Customer!]! @juniper(ownership: "owned")
}

type Mutation {
  createCustomer(
    name: String!,
    email: String!,
  ): Customer! @juniper(ownership: "owned")
}

type Customer {
  id: ID! @juniper(ownership: "owned")
  name: String!
  email: String!
}
```

src/schema.rs

```
table! {
    customers (id) {
        id -> Unsigned<Bigint>,
        name -> Varchar,
        email -> Varchar,
        created_at -> Timestamp,
        updated_at -> Timestamp,
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error message mentions you need to implement `Queryable` for your struct `Customer` in `src/graphql.rs` (That struct in just below where the error message points to). The easiest way to do that is to just add a `#[derive(Queryable)]` to this struct.